# Django REST: How to change default field type of a ModelSerializer class

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to overwrite serializer's `data` field, which is a `CharField`,like this:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField

class ActivitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = JSONField()
    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ("date_added", "start_date", "data", "number", "athlete")
```

But when I try to print the representation of the serializer  -`print(repr(my_serializer))` - the type of field `data` remains unchanged:

```
ActivitySerializer(<Activity: START DATE: 2018-11-19 06:08:49+00:00, ID: 1973222369, DATE ADDED: 2018-11-20 18:07:32.818798+00:00>):
    date_added = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    start_date = DateTimeField(required=False)
    data = CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    number = IntegerField(required=False)
    athlete = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Athlete.objects.all(), required=False)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrite serializer's data field " ?

Comment: Change its type from `CharField` to `JSONField`

Comment: I guess it says CharFiels because it expects data to be a string, by default. But when you see it in the browser, you will see json data.

Comment: I will see JSON data, but with backslashes escaping double qoutes. This is becasue JSON is stored as string in model field , and then it is serialized again to string through serializers CharField. But I found solution to this by creating custom serializer field - my question is about someting else:)

Comment: try to use **`serializers.JSONField()`** instead of `jsonfield.JSONField()`